# Parsing JSON W/ API Key

Tags: java, android, json, api, parsing

Im new to JSON and Parsing data, etc. Im using GSON and trying to pull the JSONArray "systems" and then display the JSONObject's "system_name" then display it.
 Here below is a example of the JSON data to be pulled.

```
 {
"systems": [
  {
  "city": "Petaluma",
  "country": "US",
  "postal_code": "94954",
  "state": "CA",
  "status": "normal",
  "system_id": 66,
  "system_name": "Smith Residence",
  "system_public_name": "Residential System",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
},
{
  "city": "Atherton",
  "country": "US",
  "postal_code": "94954",
  "state": "CA",
  "status": "error",
  "system_id": 77,
  "system_name": "Jones Residence",
  "system_public_name": "Jones Residence",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
}
 ]
}
```

The API uses an API_KEY to authenticate and is used like this

https://api.company.com/api/systems?key=123ABC

### Code

```
public class PullJSONData extends Activity {

TextView systemsTextView;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    systemsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    this.retrieveSystems();
}
void retrieveSystems() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...",
            "Retrieving data...", true, true);
    SystemsRetrieverAsyncTask task = new SystemsRetrieverAsyncTask();
    task.execute();
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new CancelListener(task));
}

private class SystemsRetrieverAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Response response;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "https://api.company.com/api";
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine()
                    .getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode
                        + " for URL " + url);
                return null;
            }

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream httpResponseStream = getResponseEntity.getContent();
            Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponseStream);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            SystemList systemList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SystemList.class);

            for (int i = 0; i < systemList.systems.size(); i++)
            {
               System s = systemList.systems.get(i);
            }
            this.response = gson
                    .fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (System systems : this.response.data) {

            builder.append(String.format(
                    "<br>System: <b>%s</b><br>City: <b>%s</b><br><br>",
                    systems.getCountry(), systems.getCity()));

        }

        systemsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

}

private class CancelListener implements OnCancelListener {

    AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> cancellableTask;

    public CancelListener(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
        cancellableTask = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        cancellableTask.cancel(true);
    }

}
```

### Responce

```
public class Response {

ArrayList<System> data;

public Response() {
    data = new ArrayList<System>();
}
```

### System

```
public class System {

String city;
String country;

public System() {

    this.city = "";
    this.country = "";
}

public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}
```

### SystemList

```
public class SystemList {
public List<System> systems;

public SystemList() { systems = new ArrayList<System>(); }
}
```

If you need to see full source, FIND IT [HERE](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/)

### Current Issues

- NullPointerException
- Error 401 from URL https://api.company.com/api/systems/

  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678): java.lang.NullPointerException
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at com.jaisonbrooks.enlightenme.PullJSONData$SystemsRetrieverAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PullJSONData.java:96)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at com.jaisonbrooks.enlightenme.PullJSONData$SystemsRetrieverAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PullJSONData.java:1)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native     Method)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
  04-29 15:43:25.735: E/AndroidRuntime(3678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

Another option (similar to jackson above) is to use the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. Does an excellent job with json handling. Also it's very well documented and understood.

EDIT:

Ok so after looking at your code you seem to be over complicating the System and SystemList classes.

```
public class System {
    public String city;
    public String country;
    public String postal_code;
    public String state;
    public String status;
    public String system_id;
    public String system_name;
    public String system_public_name;
    public String timezone;
}

public class SystemsList {
    public List<System> systems;
}
```

All you need to do is to ensure that the names in your json map to the names in your data models.

I've also included a fully generic GsonSerializer so that it can be reused for other gson responses

```
public class GsonSerializer 
{
private static final String TAG = "GsonSerializer";

public static <T> Object seralizeData (String response, T t)
{
    Gson serializer = new Gson();

    try 
    {
        return serializer.fromJson(response, t.getClass());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e(TAG, "deserialization failure: ".concat(response));
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

The way you would work with this class is as follows.

```
 // Where mData is a class of type T
 mData = (T) GsonSerializer.seralizeData(Json, mData); 
 // or in a specific example
 mSystemList = (SystemList) GsonSerializer.seralizeData(Json, new SystemList());
```

This should give you enough that you can pretty much plug and play. Some small tweaks are probably required.

Comment: I've updated my code by using the GSON library, can you take a 2nd look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment you use a library like [Jackcon](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

The response you get is a [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) `{...}` with a [`JOSNArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) `[...]` named "systems" inside.

If you want to parse the elements (more `JSONObject`s) within the `JSONArray` you can do so by using the classes provided by the [org.json](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) package that is being distributed with Android or use another JSON library like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org).

First you must extract the data from the outer most `JSONObject`. To do so, call [`myJSONObject.getJSONArray("systems");`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29). The resulting value will be of the type `JSONArray`. You can iterate over it's [`length()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length%28%29) calling [`getJSONObject(i)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject%28int%29) at each position.

These `JSONObject`s contain the data that you actually want to use locally.

It's good practice to create a model class containing the `JSONObject`'s elements as member variables and providing a Constructor that takes the `JSONObject` containing the objects data values.

From within this Constructor you can then read the values of the JSONObject like this: `this.city = myJSONObject.getString("city");`

For starters you can go with the org.json package and get familiar with [JSON](http://www.json.org) itself.

Comment: I've reupdated my question with some example code. can you take a second look.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a JSON Serialization library. Google's own [**GSON**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is the best I have found.  For your data you would do as follows:

Create a model that matches a system (I use getters and setters, some just use public fields, to each his own):

```
public class System
{
   private String city;

   public String getCity { return city; }
   public void setCity(string c) { city = c; }

   private String country;

   public String getCountry{ return country; }
   public void setCountry(string c) { country = c; }

   // .. the rest of the fields here
}

public class SystemList
{
    public List<System> systems;

    public SystemList() { systems = new List<System>(); }
}
```

Then to serialize your top level object, do the following (note, your JSON is wrapped in curly braces {} which implies a top level unnamed object.  We'll represent that with **SystemList**)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SystemList systemList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SystemList.class);

for (int i = 0; i < systemList.systems.size(); i++)
{
   System s = systemList.systems.get(i);
   // do something with system
}
```

Comment: Added some new code per your recommendations, However im getting a NullPointerException - Looks like also a Error 401,

Comment: 401 would come from the service end, not the client.  I tested my code against your JSON and it worked